# How do I get a Hibernate Interceptor to pick up certain superclass fields?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have some entities. For example

```
@Entity
@IdClass(SecurityUserPublisherId.class)
@Table(name="SECUSERPUB")
public class SecurityUserPublisher extends Auditable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(name="USERPUB_CONTACTID", updatable=false, nullable=false)
    protected Integer contactId = null;
    @Id
    @Column(name="USERPUB_PUBID", updatable=false, nullable=false)
    protected Integer publisherId = null;

    public SecurityUserPublisher() {
        super();
        setAudited(true);
    }

    public SecurityUserPublisher(SecurityUserPublisher securityUserPublisher) {
        setContactId(securityUserPublisher.getContactId());
        setPublisherId(securityUserPublisher.getPublisherId());
    }

    public Integer getContactId() {return contactId;}

    public void setContactId(Integer contactId) {this.contactId = contactId;}

    public Integer getPublisherId() {return publisherId;}

    public void setPublisherId(Integer publisherId) {this.publisherId = publisherId;}

    @Transient
    @Override
    public String getPrimaryKeyDisplay() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (contactId == null) {
            sb.append(" contactId: null");
        } else {
            sb.append(" contactId: " + contactId.toString());
        }
        if (publisherId == null) {
            sb.append(" publisherId: null");
        } else {
            sb.append(" publisherId: " + publisherId.toString());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Transient
    @Override
    public String getAuditDetail() {
        return new ToStringBuilder(this).append("contactId", contactId).append("publisherId", publisherId).toString();
    }
}
```

They extend the Auditable class

```
public abstract class Auditable implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected Integer auditContactId = null;
    protected Boolean audited = false;

    public void setAuditContactId(Integer auditContactId) {this.auditContactId = auditContactId;}
    public Integer getAuditContactId() {return auditContactId;}
    public Boolean isAudited() {return audited;}
    protected void setAudited(Boolean audited) {this.audited = audited;}
    public abstract String getPrimaryKeyDisplay();
    public abstract String getAuditDetail();
}
```

And I have an interceptor

```
public class AuditInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Set<Auditable> inserts = new HashSet<>();
    private Set<Auditable> updates = new HashSet<>();
    private Set<Auditable> deletes = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types)
        throws CallbackException {

        if (entity != null && entity instanceof Auditable && ((Auditable)entity).isAudited()){
            System.out.println(entity.toString());
            System.out.println(id.toString());
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(state));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(propertyNames));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(types));
            inserts.add((Auditable)entity);
        }
        return super.onSave(entity, id, state, propertyNames, types);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types)
        throws CallbackException {

        if (entity instanceof Auditable && ((Auditable)entity).isAudited()){
            updates.add((Auditable)entity);
        }
        return super.onFlushDirty(entity, id, currentState, previousState, propertyNames, types);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDelete(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {

        if (entity instanceof Auditable && ((Auditable)entity).isAudited()){
            System.out.println(entity.toString());
            System.out.println(id.toString());
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(state));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(propertyNames));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(types));
            deletes.add((Auditable)entity);
        }
    }

    //called before commit into database
    @Override
    public void preFlush(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Iterator iterator) {
    }

    //called after committed into database
    @Override
    public void postFlush(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Iterator iterator) {
        try {
            for (Iterator<Auditable> iter = inserts.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
                Auditable entity = iter.next();
                iter.remove();
                logIt("Saved", entity);
            }

            for (Iterator<Auditable> iter = updates.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
                Auditable entity = iter.next();
                iter.remove();
                logIt("Updated", entity);
            }

            for (Iterator<Auditable> iter = deletes.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
                Auditable entity = iter.next();
                iter.remove();
                logIt("Deleted", entity);
            }

        } finally {
            inserts.clear();
            updates.clear();
            deletes.clear();
        }
    }

    public void logIt(String action, Auditable entity) {
        if (!entity.isAudited()) {
            return;
        }
        Session tempSession = SessionHelper.getSession().getSession().getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Audit auditRecord = new Audit();
        auditRecord.setAction(action);
        auditRecord.setContactId(entity.getAuditContactId());
        auditRecord.setDetail(entity.getAuditDetail()); 
        auditRecord.setCreatedTimestamp(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())); 
        auditRecord.setEntityPK(entity.getPrimaryKeyDisplay()); 
        auditRecord.setEntityName(entity.getClass().toString());
        tempSession.save(auditRecord);
        tempSession.flush();
    }

}
```

I can create entities

```
final SecurityUserPublisher secUserPub = new SecurityUserPublisher();
secUserPub.setContactId(currentUser.getContactId());
secUserPub.setPublisherId(publisher.getId());
secUserPub.setAuditContactId(parentFrame.getUser().getContactId());
try {
    SessionHelper.getCreate().createSecurityUserPublisher(secUserPub);
```

and the audit trail looks good
AUDIT_ID 120385
AUDIT_ACTION Saved
AUDIT_DETAIL SecurityUserPublisher@678541a[contactId=8721,publisherId=360]  AUDIT_CREATEDTS 2019-04-04 13:52:57
AUDIT_ENTITYPK contactId: 8721 publisherId: 360
AUDIT_ENTITYNAME SecurityUserPublisher
AUDIT_CONTACTID 7341

But when I try to delete

```
final SecurityUserPublisher secUserPub = SessionHelper.getSession().getSecurityUserPublisher(currentUser.getContactId(), publisher.getId());
secUserPub.setAuditContactId(parentFrame.getUser().getContactId());
try {
    SessionHelper.getRemove().removeSecurityUserPublisher(secUserPub);
```

the audit trail contact id is null, even though I expressly set it before calling the remove.
AUDIT_ID 120386
AUDIT_ACTION Deleted
AUDIT_DETAIL SecurityUserPublisher@1d184bc8[contactId=8721,publisherId=360] 
AUDIT_CREATEDTS 2019-04-04 13:53:35 
AUDIT_ENTITYPK contactId: 8721 publisherId: 360 
AUDIT_ENTITYNAME SecurityUserPublisher
AUDIT_CONTACTID null

So, how do I get the onDelete to show the contactId in the Audit table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [@MappedSuperclass](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html) annotation on Auditable class. Otherwise Hibernate ignores super class fields and fields of Auditable class are not saved into DB.

Comment: If I do that then the database throws a `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name` because the Auditable fields are not annotated and they don't match any column name in the table. The fields exist on another audit table. If I annotate them with @Transient, I don't get the exception any more, but they also don't make it to the Interceptor.

Comment: Either the fields should be in the Database (in which case, you should annotate them) or else they are transient and are not persisted, in which case, hibernate does not treat them like database fields. What you are describing is that sometimes you want them to be persistent fields, and sometimes you want them to be ignored. But it appears to me that you don't give hibernate the information that it needs to make that distinction. I'm not actually sure that you can. Wouldn't it be a better solution to "fix" your class hierarchy so that it reflects what you need?

Comment: @NathanKummer All I want to do is have a Hibernate Interceptor log the person that made a particular change to an Audit table. But it doesn't have access to the username because that isn't transmitted to the server unless the field is persisted.

Comment: I ended up using this although it made us put a field on every table we want to audit, that really doesn't mean anything to that table (other than the last person to change it).